# Limit characters in redactor wysiwyg field

Tags: redactor, fieldtypes, wysiwyg

I'm trying to limit the amount of characters by adding the 'limiter' plugin to the redactor field which can be found here:

http://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/limiter/

I've added the limiter.js file to my /craft/app/resources/lib/redactor/plugins folder.

Next I changed the Standard.json in /craft/config/redactor/Standard.json to

```
{
 focus: true,
 limiter: 20,
 buttons: ['html','formatting','bold','italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image','video'],
 plugins: ['fullscreen','limiter'],
 toolbarFixedBox: true
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Anybody a good suggestion how I can fix this easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the JS with a Craft plugin, either a custom one making use of `includeJsResource` (see [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/267/can-a-plugin-add-js-or-css-to-the-control-panel) for code example) or with the [Control Panel JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) plugin.