# How to limit RTF field word count?

Tags: templating, field, redactor, richtext

It is easy to set in the text field, but I don't see such option in RTF. How can I do it?

Alternatively, I can use a text field, though it doesn't output new lines as paragraphs - it is possible?

Comment: Have a look at: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9798/limit-characters-in-redactor-wysiwyg-field

Comment: Thanks, it works, though without having good "characters left" counter it makes it tough for use. I opened issue about this https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1677

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done manually with [Redactor Limiter](https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/limiter/) javascript plugin that would be side-loaded to CP with, i.e., [Control Panel JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) plugin.

Alternatively, [Redactor Extras](https://github.com/elliotlewis/Redactor-Extras) plugin for Craft can be used, that contains and loads Redactor plugins itself.