# Install Redactor plugin

Tags: redactor

I would like to install a Redactor plugin (http://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/font-color/)

I placed the fontcolor.js into **craft/app/ressources/lib/redactor/plugins**
and added
    buttons: ['fontcolor', 'backcolor']
    plugins: ['fontcolor'] to my redactor json config file.
but without success.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot,

Antoine

Answer (score 3):

If this is still required I've built a plugin, Redactor Extras: https://github.com/elliotlewis/Redactor-Extras

You can add your own JS via the Plugin. I'm updating and adding plugins from Redactors site regularly. I'll add font-color next. But good use with your own code.

Comment: Sounds very useful! Does it work with Craft 3?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the JS with a Craft plugin, either a custom one making use of `includeJsResource` (see [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/267/can-a-plugin-add-js-or-css-to-the-control-panel) for code example) or with the [Control Panel JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) plugin.