# Max character limit on WYSIWYG text editor plugin?

Tags: redactor, wysiwyg, ckeditor5

Is it possible to add a max character limit to CKEditor, Redactor, or any other rich text, or WYSIWYG plugin??

I've searched around, and I'm surprised that I have not been able to find a solution. Seems like a pretty basic feature. I would like to not have to use a third-party plugin for this one thing. But if that's the only way to do it, please indicate that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me, just changing the config file:

```
{
  "buttons": ["html", "bold", "italic"],
  "plugins": ["fullscreen", "**limiter**", "counter"],
  "linkNewTab": true,
  "toolbarFixed": true,
  **"limiter": 235**
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Imperavi, creators of Redactor provide the [Limiter plugin](https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/limiter/) to add this functionality but you would need to create a Craft plugin to add the JS, as detailed in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9881/install-redactor-plugin).