# craft.request.getParam('entryId') returns null on edit page of an entry

Tags: entry, error, null

I have a plugin that's loaded on the edit page of an entry.

Whenever I open the entry edit page, I would like to retrieve the id of this particular entry. I've tried this:
`{% set someId = craft.request.getParam('entryId') %}`

But this just returns null.

I need the id because I use it in my service: `craft.pluginName.getRecordByEntryId(someId)`.
Which will return information that's bound to that page.

I've also tried this:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries %}
{% if entry.id %}
    <p>EntryId: <input type="text" value="{{ entry.id }}"/></p>
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

But this will return all the entry id's, which I can't really use.

Any help or advice on how I should tackle this differently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your plugin getting loaded on the edit entry page?

Comment: Using this trick: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/14526/5730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`craft()->request->getParam()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#getParam-detail) is only going to check for the value as part of the query string in the URI or in POST if it is a POST request, which is why it's returning null on the edit entry page in the control panel (it isn't in either).

But since it [looks like](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/14526/57) you're using a template hook in your plugin, you can get the entry id directly from the context:

```
$entry = $context['entry'];

if (!$entry->id)
{
    // New entry
}
else
{
    $entryId = $entry->id;
}
```