# Writing a plugin that triggers on a Control Panel Template Hook?

Tags: plugin-development

I want to do something similar to [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/14526/6844) answer but for Craft 3 (eg. render some custom HTML in the Entry editing screen). I can't work out how to do this with the changed Craft 3 hooks.

Should this be registered as an event now? What class/event ID should I be using to add code to `cp.entries.edit.details`?

(I'm new to Craft plugin dev so a little unclear how to proceed here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out after browsing some existing plugins' source:

```
Craft::$app->getView()->hook('cp.entries.edit.details', function(array &$context) {
    return '<a href="#" class="btn">My Button!</a>';
});
```