# Extend a Commerce (v2) order template in the control panel

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is there a way to extend (extend, not replace) the default Commerce order templates in the control panel? 
I'd like to display important custom fields in a prominent way on the first tab. (and not tucked away on a second tab as is normal with custom fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in another question:
[Writing a plugin that triggers on a Control Panel Template Hook?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23721/writing-a-plugin-that-triggers-on-a-control-panel-template-hook?rq=1)

Based on this answer we can use:

```
Craft::$app->getView()->hook('cp.commerce.order.edit.main-pane', function(array &$context) {
    return '<a href="#" class="btn">My Button!</a>';
});
```