# Adding Custom button to CP

Tags: control-panel, events, hook

I'm trying to add a custom button in the sidebar of one of my entries.

I've found that it could be done in Craft 3 with this template hook: `cp.entries.edit.details` (e.g. [How to add a custom button at the right section of an entry?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14516/how-to-add-a-custom-button-at-the-right-section-of-an-entry/14526#14526))

In the Craft 4 upgrade documentation, it mentions that this hook [has been removed](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/updating-plugins.html#template-hooks). I found these two events -  `EVENT_DEFINE_EDITOR_CONTENT` and `EVENT_DEFINE_ADDITIONAL_BUTTONS` - but so far, I haven't been able to return html to my template.

Is there an easy way to do it in Craft 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`EVENT_DEFINE_SIDEBAR_HTML` event](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-base-element.html#event-define-sidebar-html) like so:

```
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\events\DefineHtmlEvent;
use craft\helpers\UrlHelper;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(
    Entry::class,
    Entry::EVENT_DEFINE_SIDEBAR_HTML,
    function(DefineHtmlEvent $event) {

        /** @var Entry $entry */
        $entry = $event->sender;

        // Make sure this is the correct section
        if ($entry->sectionId == 5)
        {
            // Return the button HTML
            $url = UrlHelper::url('some/path/' . $entry->id);
            $event->html .= '<a href="' . $url . '" class="btn">My Button!</a>';
        }

    }
);
```